# Tensorflow, tf.train.batch, no result

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'm a newbie about tf.train.batch, so i wrote a sample to test it. When i run the code, i got no result and the process was still running.

Have you met the same situation before? Many thanks in advance!

```
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
b = [1,2,3,4]
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([a, b],num_epochs=None,shuffle=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    for i in range(4):


        x,y = tf.train.batch([a,b], batch_size=2)


        x_,y_ =sess.run([x,y])
        print(x_,y_)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Plus, the function tf.train.slice_input_producer works. When i ignore tf.train.batch, the code becomes:

```
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
b = [1,2,3,4]
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([a, b],num_epochs=None,shuffle=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    for i in range(4):

     print(sess.run(input_queue))

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

The result is :

```
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 1]
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 2]
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 3]
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 4]
```

Comment: What's your desired result? The `tf.train.batch` is used mostly with input pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the major problem is that you didn't specify `enqueue_many` to `True` so that the it will just repeat the whole batch. You can read more at [official document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch).
Here is a working sample:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
b = [1,2,3,4]
a, b = tf.train.batch([a,b], batch_size=1, num_threads=1, capacity=4, enqueue_many=True)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord)
    for i in range(4):
        print(sess.run([a,b]))
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: xiexie dalao l.

Comment: @Jingjue.Wei don't know what you mean, but if you think this answer solved your problem please accept by clicking on the tick.

Comment: It seem works, but i have run this code yet. I will contact you if i got some problems